# Windows 7 x64 Pro not indexing PDF content?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, pdf, search

In an attemp to get rid of all the paper clutter that I receive each day, I started scanning and ORCing all my important documents last year. I was using Windows Desktop Search on Vista to index my "Administrative" folder in which I keep all these scanned documents, to be able to quickly retreive them when needed.

I upgraded to Windows 7 RTM recently (I got the x64 Pro version, via the MSDN-AA channel of my university). Since then, it seems that the content of the PDFs is not indexed anymore.

For example, I have the warranty for my GTX260 graphic card. In the PDF, using Acrobat Reader, I can search for the string "GTX260" and it finds the relevant lines. However, if I perform the same search in the folder containing the PDF, nothing is found.

I checked in the indexing options, the folder is supposed to be indexed.

Comment: When the PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms is installed on Windows 7 (version 9 does not officially support Windows 7) that the filter searches text in only some PDF files. Adobe... a new filter please!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that there is no x64 IFilter for Adobe PDF documents installed. You may want to get the [official Adobe x64 IFilter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025).

The [Foxit IFilter](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/ifilter/) is also an option but depending on the scenario you may need to purchase it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the official filter ! It's the one I used.

Answer (score 2):

There's no IFilter for PDF included with Windows. I might be wrong, but I don't think there's one included with Acrobat Reader either. You could try the FoxIt IFilter. It's free. Just installing FoxIt Reader will do the trick, I think.

http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/